# Cypher Query: Return type of relationship of paths with variable length

Tags: neo4j, cypher

users, 
I am trying to receive all paths (e.g., length < 3) , print the node titles, but also the relationship type.

Using:

```
MATCH (p0:Page {title:'New Zealand'}), (p1:Page {title:'Kiwi'}), p = (p0)-[r*..2]-(p1)
RETURN p AS path
```

Prints the paths, but the relationship is represented as {}

As I am using *..2,

```
`RETURN p,type(r)'
```

is not working(Type mismatch: expected Relationship but was Collection)

I can use a workaround like:

```
MATCH
  (p0:Page {title:'New Zealand'}),
  (p1:Page {title:'Kiwi'}),
  p = (p0)-[r]-(p3)-[r1]-(p1)
RETURN p0,type(r),p3,type(r1)
```

but with increasing pathlength, I would have executed a query for each pathlength.

I tried:

```
MATCH
  (p0:Page {title:'New Zealand'}),
  (p1:Page {title:'Kiwi'}),
  p = (p0)-[r*..2]-(p1) FOREACH(r in p | RETURN p,p0,type(r),p1)
```

-> expected Collection but was Path

Does anyone have hint?

Additional information JSON output(snippet) from Neo4j interface:

```
    {
  "results": [
    {
      "columns": [
        "p",
        "rels(p)",
        "nodes(p)"
      ],
      "data": [
        {
          "row": [
            [
              {
                "title": "New Zealand"
              },
              {},
              {
                "title": "Category:Birds of New Zealand"
              },
              {},
              {
                "title": "Kiwi"
              }
            ],
            [
              {},
              {}
            ],
            [
              {
                "title": "New Zealand"
              },
              {
                "title": "Category:Birds of New Zealand"
              },
              {
                "title": "Kiwi"
              }
            ]
          ],
          "graph": {
            "nodes": [
              {
                "id": "11120",
                "labels": [
                  "Page"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "title": "Kiwi"
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "1942858",
                "labels": [
                  "Page"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "title": "New Zealand"
                }
              },
              {
                "id": "11994493",
                "labels": [
                  "Category"
                ],
                "properties": {
                  "title": "Category:Birds of New Zealand"
                }
              }
            ],
            "relationships": [
              {
                "id": "1070940",
                "type": "To_Category",
                "startNode": "11120",
                "endNode": "11994493",
                "properties": {}
              },
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply use `extract` for extracting the type of relationships inside the path.

Based on the simple movie graph on http://console.neo4j.org :

```
MATCH p=(:Crew { name:"Neo" })-[r*3]-()
RETURN p, extract(x IN rels(p)| type(x)) AS types
```

Your query would then be :

```
MATCH (p0:Page {title:'New Zealand'}), (p1:Page {title:'Kiwi'}), 
p=(p0)-[r*..2]-(p1)
RETURN p, extract (rel in rels(p) | type(rel) ) as types
```

This will return you a collection of types :

[LOVE, KNOWS, KNOWS]

So you can have duplicates. If you need to de-duplicate them, use UNWIND and distinct :

```
MATCH (p0:Page {title:'New Zealand'}), (p1:Page {title:'Kiwi'}), 
p=(p0)-[r*..2]-(p1)
WITH p, extract (rel in rels(p) | type(rel) ) as types
UNWIND types as t
RETURN p, collect(distinct t) as types
```

**UPDATE**

I wasn't so happy with the last one, so here an easier way :

```
MATCH (p0:Page {title:'New Zealand'}), (p1:Page {title:'Kiwi'}), 
p=(p0)-[r*..2]-(p1)
UNWIND rels(p) as rel
RETURN p, collect(distinct type(rel)) as types
```

Answer (score 1):

Does using the `rels` function help you?

```
MATCH (p0:Page {title:'New Zealand'}), (p1:Page {title:'Kiwi'}), p = (p0)-[r*..2]-(p1)
RETURN p, rels(p), nodes(p)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. Unfortunately, it has the same effect:
 rels(p) [(empty), (empty)]  ; Columns: [p, rels(p), nodes(p)] current row 0: [[{title=New Zealand}, {}, {title=Category:Birds of New Zealand}, {}, {title=Kiwi}], [{}, {}], [{title=New Zealand}, {title=Category:Birds of New Zealand}, {title=Kiwi}]]. Maybe I did something wrong while building my graph (?)